# Calling Fortran from Python using CFFI

Tags: python, windows, dll, fortran, python-cffi

I am trying to reproduce [this example](http://scientific-software-diary.com/?p=29) on Windows. Here are the corresponding fortran codes

> fortran_wrapper.f90

```
MODULE FORTRAN_WRAPPER

USE ISO_C_BINDING, ONLY: C_INT
USE YOUR_FORTRAN_MODULE

IMPLICIT NONE

CONTAINS
  SUBROUTINE C_WRAPPER_YOUR_SUBR(ARG1) BIND(C, NAME = "C_WRAPPER_YOUR_SUBR")

     INTEGER(C_INT), INTENT(IN), VALUE :: ARG1  

     CALL YOUR_SUBR(ARG1)

  END SUBROUTINE C_WRAPPER_YOUR_SUBR

END MODULE FORTRAN_WRAPPER
```

> fortran_code.f90

```
 MODULE YOUR_FORTRAN_MODULE

  CONTAINS
  
    SUBROUTINE YOUR_SUBR(ARG1)

     IMPLICIT NONE

     INTEGER, INTENT(IN) :: ARG1

     WRITE(*,*) 'The values is: ', ARG1

   END SUBROUTINE YOUR_SUBR

 END MODULE YOUR_FORTRAN_MODULE
```

Here is the corresponding calling python code

> python_prog.py

```
from cffi import FFI
import os
ffi = FFI()
dll_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'dll_name.dll')
lib = ffi.dlopen(dll_path)

ffi.cdef("void C_WRAPPER_YOUR_SUBR(int arg1);")

arg1 = 1

lib.C_WRAPPER_YOUR_SUBR(arg1)
```

The `dll_name.dll` was created using intel fortran compiler in the following way

`ifort /dll fortran_code.f90 fortran_wrapper.f90 /exe:dll_name.dll`

After running the `python python_prog.py` I got the following error

`AttributeError: function/symbol 'C_WRAPPER_YOUR_SUBR' not found in library 'dll_name.dll': error 0x7f`

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: I don't know Fortran tools, but maybe the problem is the same as https://groups.google.com/g/python-cffi/c/djQHpdoz1bo/m/LWKKLARRDQAJ ?

Comment: @ArminRigo Your answer/link helped a lot. Thank you. It is now working. I just added ```!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT :: C_WRAPPER_YOUR_SUBR``` into ```fortran_wrapper.f90``` and created the dll again. Now, there is no error after calling python code.

Answer (score 0):

(Copying here the answer from this external forum) On Windows, you need to make the function exported from the
DLL. In other words, whereas on POSIX systems all non-static
functions are exported by shared libraries (by default), it does not
work like this on Windows. In C, you would need either to use a .def file, or say in the C source:

```
__declspec(dllexport) int myfunction(int a) {
   ...
}
```

(Also copying here your comment) The Fortran equivalent seems to be to add this to your `.f90` file:

```
!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT :: C_WRAPPER_YOUR_SUBR
```